# When trying to display an image with a URL on tkinter, i get the error that there is no module named PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to display an image via its URL with the following code (this is an example image i took from google):

```
from tkinter import *
import pyrebase
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

multiQ = Tk()
multiQ.title("Multiple-Choice Question")
multiQ.resizable(0,0)

header = LabelFrame(multiQ, bg="white")
content = LabelFrame(multiQ, bg="white")

header.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
homeButton=Button(content,width=50,height=50)
try:
    homeIcon=PhotoImage(file="yes.png")
    homeButton.config(image=homeIcon)
    homeButton.image = homeIcon
except TclError:
    print("Home")
homeButton.grid(row=1, sticky="w", padx=15, pady=2)

#this is the bit of code where i want to display the image and an error is occuring
my_page = urlopen("https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftowardsdatascience.com%2F3-numpy-image-transformations-on-baby-yoda-c27c1409b411&psig=AOvVaw18g0gcyX-PS9EMi0WxOhGT&ust=1596279067474000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMDnw5Op9-oCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD")
my_picture = io.BytesIO(my_page.read())
pil_img = Image.open(my_picture)
tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_img)
titleHeader = Label(content, text="Question Image here",pady=15, padx=20, bg="white", font=("Ariel",20, "bold"), anchor="w", relief="solid", image=tk_img)
titleHeader.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=15, pady=5, ipadx=350, ipady=225)


aButton = Button(content, text="A", font=("Ariel",35, "bold"), borderwidth=2, relief="solid", activebackground="#12a8e3", bg="#12a8e3")
aButton.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=(25,50), ipadx=30, ipady=20)

bButton = Button(content, text="B", font=("Ariel",35, "bold"), borderwidth=2, relief="solid", activebackground="#12a8e3", bg="#12a8e3")
bButton.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=(25,50), ipadx=30, ipady=20)

cButton = Button(content, text="C", font=("Ariel",35, "bold"), borderwidth=2, relief="solid", activebackground="#12a8e3", bg="#12a8e3")
cButton.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=(25,50), ipadx=30, ipady=20)

dButton = Button(content, text="D", font=("Ariel",35, "bold"), borderwidth=2, relief="solid", activebackground="#12a8e3", bg="#12a8e3")
dButton.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=(25,50), ipadx=30, ipady=20)

header.grid(row=0, sticky='NSEW')
content.grid(row=1, sticky='NSEW')

multiQ.mainloop()
```

I get the error "No module named PIL". I have downloaded PIL in the command prompt and have tried "import PIL" in the code, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: i think python 3.8

Comment: Did you install the `Pillow` module via `pip`?

Answer (score 0):

pil and pillow, in most cases are not supported by python version 3.7 and 3.8. if your code are without bug. downgrade your project interpreter to python 3.6. then pip install pillow.

Comment: How would i do this?

Comment: How would i do this?

Comment: im using pycharm

Comment: Where do you get the information that the pillow module is not supported by Python 3.7 and 3.8?  It works fine in my Python 3.8 environment.

Comment: @acw1668 how do you import stuff from PIL?

Comment: Same like your code: `from PIL import Image, ImageTk`.

Comment: @acw1668 I said some cases and not all cases. it raises os errors that has nothing to do with the code, it couldn't work for me until i downgraded my python version.

Comment: @stackuser7 make sure there is no bug in your code, try 'pip install pillow' in your terminal( you will find it at the bottom in pycharm). then run you code again. if it raises the same error  then go  and install python 3.6 to your system, remember to add to path. go to pycharm add configuration, you'll can change your intepreter there.

Comment: @lvingstone thanks that worked by installing in the codes terminal

Answer (score 0):

your `python` version is 3.8

```
pip3.8 install pil
pip3.8 install pillow
```